# Perl subroutine sort my_compare (@d);

Tags: perl, subroutine

I am taking an online perl class and we started subroutines. The professor used this example:

```
@d = (1, 5, 2, 9, 8, 7, 10, 11);

@c = sort my_compare (@d);

# Print the result
print "Before sort:\t".join(", ", @d) . "\n";
print "After sort:\t".join(", ", @c) . "\n";    

sub my_compare
{
    if ($a < $b) { return -1; }
    elsif ($a > $b) { return 1; }
    else  { return 0; }
}
```

I dont understand the  *@c = sort my_compare (@d);* statement and why I cannot rename the variables *$a* and *$b*. This is completely different than what I am used to doing for soubroutines in languages like C and C++.

Could somebody explain this to me?

Thank you for your help!
Zahra

Comment: I couldn't tell you anything that [`perldoc -f sort`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/sort.html) doesn't already say ten time better.

Comment: Re "I cannot rename the variables $a and $b", What do you mean by that?

Comment: The variables $a and $b are special in the context of the sort function.  They get set to the values of the two elements the sort function is currently working on.

Comment: $a and $b are special package variables. They are sort comparison routine variables.

Comment: Starting the subroutine chapter with sort subroutines seems unnecessarily complicated.

Answer (score 2):

Unlike many other languages, Perl is like slang. Less consistent, but full of very useful shortcuts. As Larry Wall stated:

> In general, they (Perl operators) do what you want, unless you want consistency.

For the C library `qsort` function, you always need to provide a function pointer called `compar`, that will do the actual comparison of value pairs.

```
void qsort(void *base, size_t nmemb, size_t size,
           int (*compar)(const void *, const void *));
```

This is very similar in Perl, but providing comparison code is optional.
This uses the default built-in alphabetic comparison.

```
sort @d
```

The whole reason of the above exercise is to replace the alphabetic comparison with a numeric one. You can provide custom comparison code in the form of a subroutine name or a block.

```
sort subname @d;
sort { $a <=> $b } @d;
```

The above is the most simple solution to your problem, using the numeric comparison operator `<=>`. It does the same as `sub my_compare`.

And well, `$a` and `$b` are just built in. Perl has no function prototypes with parameter names, so they had to name it somehow.

See http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/sort.html for further details.

Comment: Actually, [Perl does have built-in function signatures](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsub.html#Signatures) with parameter names, since perl v5.20.0. However, that's a fairly recent and experimental feature, so no one actually uses it.